# How to get datetime day with 0 before day even if day is below 10

Tags: sql-server, datetime

The title might no be very enlightening, but heres the question:

In mssql I have a datetime which when i select it it is in the following format:
Sep 2 2014

now this is not good, i want it to be like this: Sep 02 2014

I need the 0 before the 2, I tried converting it to a varchar which obviously did not prove useful...

How can i format the date to look like this?

Comment: So, is it actually a `DATETIME` datatype?, or a string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you're using style code 7.  You want 107.

```
SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR, GETUTCDATE(), 107)
```

`Sep 02, 2014`

Comment: This is good, but is there a way i can remove the comma? it is very important.

Comment: Why not leave the formatting to the front end? Doing this in sql is the wrong place.

Comment: Guys i have a problem and mistake. I need the date to be like this:
Sep 02 2014 HH:mm
i need the hours and minutes too...

Comment: @user3238509:  Where are you displaying this?  If you have a front end, you should be formatting it there, as Sean Lange said above.

Comment: @user3238509:  You may need to do it custom, then.  Try `SELECT FORMAT(GETDATE(), 'MMM dd yyyy HH:mm')`

Comment: @user3238509 `REPLACE(CONVERT(VARCHAR(12), GETUTCDATE(), 107),',','') + ' ' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(5),GETUTCDATE(),108)`

Answer (score 0):

or...

```
-- Sep 02 2014 HH:mm
declare @timestamp [datetime] = current_timestamp;
select convert([sysname], @timestamp, 107) + N' '
   + cast(datepart(hour, @timestamp) as [sysname])
   + N':'
   + cast(datepart(minute, @timestamp) as [sysname]);
```